# Is there a way to `cat` a terminal's screen?

Tags: linux, terminal

I just switched from [st](https://st.suckless.org/) to [alacritty](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty). The main reason I was using st was for its [external pipe](https://st.suckless.org/patches/externalpipe/) which allows me to quickly and easily grab some of the terminal's output (as an example on st's page).

Is there a way to `cat`/pipe a terminal's output like with st?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no generic method of doing this.

Tty devices do not have a built-in screen buffer, and they do not have any built-in understanding of the terminal graphics control codes, either. They're just fancy bidirectional pipes which transfer data between the "host" program (terminal emulator) and the rest (shell and CLI tools).

Actually interpreting that data and drawing a character grid is done by the terminal emulator app, and the "output" only exists as internal memory structures in that process. (This is what leads to different TEs supporting different capabilities, such as colors.)

So making this data accessible out-of-band is also the decision of each individual terminal-emulator app, and most simply don't do that.